# MaterialDesign PackIcon issues when using AssemblyResolve

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using MaterialDesignInXAML.

The libraries referenced by program are so large that the are compressed when building.

And compressed libraries are loading dynamically when program start.

All libraries are identified loading successfully. (Debug - window - module)

The problem arises here.

Here is below design code.

**This code does not cause any problems.**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" Width="32" Height="32" Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Add, Size=24}"/>
```

[Normal Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBA4p.png)

**But this code cause problems.**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" Width="32" Height="32">
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Add" Width="24" Height="24"/>
</Button>
```

[Strange Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmvAR.png)

The first code result load the icon normally. But second code result is icon are reset.

After research this problem, i think there is a problem in MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf library.
But i could not solve this problem for a week.

**Loading the library statically causes no problems.**

Is there a solution to this problem??

[Example git repository](https://github.com/andre-reed/example)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this problem.

The problem is Binding Context.

Here is solution.

```
static Dictionary<string, Assembly> loadedAssemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();

    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        var name = args.LoadedAssembly.FullName.Substring(0, args.LoadedAssembly.FullName.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

        if (!loadedAssemblies.ContainsKey(name))
            loadedAssemblies.Add(name, args.LoadedAssembly);
    }

    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

        if (loadedAssemblies.ContainsKey(name))
            return loadedAssemblies[name];

        var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(name));
        if (resources.Count() > 0)
        {
            string resourceName = resources.First();
            using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    byte[] assembly = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(assembly, 0, assembly.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Dll file load : " + resourceName);
                    return Assembly.Load(assembly);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```